# How do you compose an unescaped Unicode string in Haskell by parsing the escaped string?

Tags: haskell, unicode

I am parsing some text which might be "\u3200". Parsing this and converting to decimal, I know the integer sequence should be 12800. Now, I want to put this back together; I might do the following:

```
toPrintedChar x = return "\\x" ++ x
```

However, this returns an escaped sequence, and will not print the Unicode character associated with it. It is unclear to me how I can create a new string which does not have the escaped character.

I can create the string myself:

```
toPrintedChar x = return "\x12800"
```

and this does print the Unicode representation. I am wondering how I can do this generally?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `[toEnum 12800 :: Char]`. You probably want to avoid using `return` for this -- I see no need for a monad here. Also be sure to print the string with `putStrLn` and not with `show` or `print` that add quoting/escaping.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me! PS: fair! monads were used in the context of the original function but I removed most of the irrelevant code (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an integer value into a string made of that Unicode code point, it is enough to convert the number into a `Char` and then put it in a list. E.g.,

```
myString :: String
myString = [ toEnum 12800 ]
```